# Windows 7 admin can't edit hosts file anymore

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file

The question is simple. Suddenly I can't edit my hosts file on win7 anymore.

I am running notepad as administrator, i get access denied saving the file.

Under the security tab of the file it says administrators have read/write permission.
The owner is SYSTEM and i can't seem to change that.

I can edit the file running windows in safe mode.

What can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the file doesn't have readonly flag set.

The other issue could be that some protection software installed on your computer prevents editing this file. Try disabling antivirus and similar software temporarely to check if this is the case.

Comment: Avira antivirus was blocking that file. Cheers.